# Should this function be public or private?

Tags: php, function, codeigniter

I am verifying the email in database in form validation in CodeIgniter by using callback in rule. For example

```
$this -> form_validation -> set_rules( 'email', 'Email address', 'trim|valid_email|callback_email_exists' );
```

The email_exists function is:

```
public function email_exists($email)
    {
        $this -> load -> model('account_model');
        $exists = $this -> account_model -> email_registered( $email );
        if ( $exists == true )
        {
            $this -> form_validation -> set_message ( 'email_exists', 'Email already exists.');
            return false;
        }
        return true;        
    }
```

It works fine. However, shouldn't the above `email_exists` function be a private function instead of public? 
I try to make it private like `private function _email_exists($email)` and i call back it by `callback__email_exists`

However I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to private method Account::_email_exists() from context 'CI_Form_validation' in ....(line number)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that it should be private?

Comment: In CI within a controller, and many other frameworks, a non-private function can be accessed as a method from the URI. One reason, at least. `site.com/controller/email_exists` *could* cause unwanted side effects.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal , exactly what @Ross said.

Comment: @Roman, is this function inside your controller?

Comment: @Ross, the function asks for a parameter, so `site.com/controller/email_exists` could not trigger the function without errors actually

Comment: @Starx yes, but that was an example.

Comment: `email_exists` sounds like it _retrieves_ information, and thus should not have side effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to call it from outside the object (whether as callback or directly) it should be public

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
$rules['field'] = 'callback__email_exists';
$this->validation->set_rules($rules);

function _email_exists() {
  // Normal callback function rules
}
```

By sure to append two underscores to the callback instead of just one.

Don't forget to add the underscore to the message rule as well:

`$this->validation->set_message('_email_exists', 'The email already exists');`

Comment: What does changing the function name give you?

Answer (score 0):

You are validating the email, on the basis of your model `account_model`, so this makes the function more centered to the private boundary. You will not achieve anything significant, by making this function public, instead you can make this function what it is

```
A PRIVATE FUNCTION TO CHECK EMAILS FOR MODEL account_model
```